# Android SQLite table is missing a column

Tags: php, android, sqlite

The application interact with PHP Classes to get data from MySQL and using SQLite to store user data on the device, but it gives me the error messages. Could someone kindly help me to fix ?

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqliteData";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_ROLE = "role";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_ROLE + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String id, String name, String role) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, id); // id
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_ROLE, role); // Role

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("role", cursor.getString(3));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
E/JSON(373): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"id":"013","user":{"name":"Mike Burton","role":"Developer"}}

I/Database(373): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table login has no column named role

E/Database(373): Error inserting id=013 role=Developer name=Mike Burton

E/Database(373): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named role: , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(id, role, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: If you have altered `CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE` at any point you need to explicitly drop the old tables and create new ones. One of the easiest ways to do this is to add 1 to `DATABASE_VERSION`.

Comment: You also have an sql injection put `anything' OR '1'='1` in the password field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have modified.the schema but not increased the version (so the DB didn't get rebuilt with your changes).  If that is the case, you can remove/reinstall your app or increment the DB version so `onUpgrade` gets called.

Comment: @tvdog.  Great!  If you could accept the answer (click the check mark) that would be cool.  That lets everyone know your issue is solved, and gives credit to the person who helped you.